# nhibernate update

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this function

- always it returns true but the problem is that it modifies the table User but it doesn't modify the table Useracl
- how can I correct this code?

  ```
  try
  {
      NHibernate.ISession nhSession= User.OpenSession();
      using (var tx = nhSession.BeginTransaction())
      { 
          User u = new User() { 
              Account = acc, 
              Identification = identification, 
              ContactEmail = mail, 
              ContactName = nom, 
              ContactPhone = phone, 
              NotifyEmail = notify, 
              Password = mot 
          };

          nhSession.SaveOrUpdate(u);
          Useracl ua = new Useracl { Account = acc, UserID = identification, AccessLevel = 1, AclID = acc };
          nhSession.SaveOrUpdate(ua);
          tx.Commit();
          return true;
      }
  }
  catch
  {   
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: You can start by making it readable. We're not living compilers. Then you can post your NH mappings.

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? You'll find it easier to fix if you don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: There is no exception, the transaction commits. The second object doesn't get saved. @developer, please post your class definitions as well as your NHibernate mappings.

Comment: @Lee if i use ( if else ) the same thing !!!!

Comment: Post your mappings, and I can help you.

Comment: <class name="User" table="users" >
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="Identification" column="userID"  />
          <key-property name="Account"  column="accountID" />
      </composite-id>
 <property name="Type" column="userType"  /> 
 <property name="Password" column="password"  /> 
 <property name="Gender" column="gender"   /> 
 <property name="NotifyEmail" column="notifyEmail"  /> 
 <property name="ContactName" column="contactName"  /> 
 <property name="ContactPhone" column="contactPhone"  /> 
 <property name="ContactEmail" column="contactEmail" /> 
       
    </class>

Comment: <class name="Useracl" table="useracl" >
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="UserID" column="userID"  /> 
            <key-property name="AclID" column="aclID"  />
          <key-property name="Account"  column="accountID"  />
        </composite-id>
        <property name="AccessLevel" column="accessLevel"   /> 
        <property name="Description" column="description"  /> 
        <property name="LastUpdateTime" column="lastUpdateTime"   /> 
        <property name="CreationTime" column="creationTime"  /> 
    </class>

Comment: Do you realize there's an edit button and that you can format your code to not look like the apocalypse? I'm sorry, but if you can't be arsed to post an easily readable question I'm not gonna bother deciphering this scripture.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate doesn't know whether to save (ie. insert) or update your Useracl instance because it's mapped with a composite id.  You need to tell it explicitly whether you're saving a new instance or updating an existing one.  In your case, you need to call:

```
nhsession.Save(ua);
```

instead of

```
nhsession.SaveOrUpdate(ua);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   nhSession.SaveOrUpdate(u);

       Useracl ua = new Useracl() { 
        Account = acc, 
        UserID = identification, 
        AccessLevel = 1, 
        AclID = acc 
       };
   nhSession.SaveOrUpdate(ua);
   tx.Commit();
```